# How to change SDK version asp netcore in Rider IDE?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rider

How can I change the sdk version from 6 to 5 when creating an asp.netcore
The option appears disabled

i have netcore 3.1, sdk 5 and sdk6 installed

[image]
I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x) file to your solution folder

Comment: Thanks.
besides modifying the global.json, modify .sln.DotSettings.user with the same version and it worked, thank you very much

Comment: Thnaks. You can always check the current sdk version. In your solution folder type dotnet --version